# Aside from the Pyramids, what is the tallest man-made structure still standing in Europe & the Near East from ancient times?

Tags: ancient-history, building

In the Americas, there is [La Danta Temple](https://www.realmofhistory.com/2015/11/13/10-tallest-man-made-architectural-triumphs-from-our-ancient-world/) (built c300 BC, 230 ft / 70.10m) in modern-day Guatemala. In Asia (Far East and South Asia), there is the [Ruwanwelisaya](https://www.realmofhistory.com/2015/11/13/10-tallest-man-made-architectural-triumphs-from-our-ancient-world/) (built c300 BC, 300 ft / 91.44m) in Sri Lanka. What is there in Europe?

The Wikipedia page [History of the world's tallest buildings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_world%27s_tallest_buildings) makes no mention of anything between the Great Pyramids and Lincoln Cathedral (1300). The [List of Greek and Roman architectural records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Roman_architectural_records) doesn't come up with anything more than the [Pont du Gard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pont_du_Gard) at 160 ft / 48.77m (or [155 ft / 47.24m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Roman_architectural_records#Miscellaneous), depending on which Wiki article you believe). The [Colosseum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colosseum) is another possible candidate at 157 ft / 47.85m (or 159 ft / 48.46m according to [The Colosseum.net](http://www.the-colosseum.net/architecture/numeri_en.htm))

[image: Pont du Gard, Colosseum]
*The [Pont du Gard](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/Pont_du_Gard_004.jpg/1024px-Pont_du_Gard_004.jpg) and the [Colosseum](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b5/Colosseum_Roma_2009.jpg/1024px-Colosseum_Roma_2009.jpg).*

To clarify, by 'ancient times' I mean any time up to the fall of the Western Roman Empire. However, I'd also be interested in anything taller than the examples above which was built before 1000 AD i.e. Early Medieval.

I'm only interested in man-made structures which are still standing, even if not in their entirety.

Comment: [Tallest structures in Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_structures_in_Europe#History)

Comment: @ Mark C. Wallace. Unfortunately, the link  
Tallest structures in Europe only goes back to 1180, not ancient times.

Comment: I know there is no obligation to do so but it would be useful if the downvoter could explain why this question deserves to be downvoted. Criticism which is constructive is welcome and can help the OP to make improvements. Criticism with no explanation / reason serves no purpose. Please be constructive.

Comment: This question just makes me sad that they never rebuilt the Colossus of Rhodes.

Comment: So the Hagia Sophia @ 182' falls outside of your parameters time-wise then.

Comment: I'm interested in Early Medieval also.

Comment: Would walls (defense Structure) also count? the limes in germany was 550 km long, parts of it still exist. Hadrians wall was 118 km long, also some sections still exist. There are also some more roman limes in other european countries. It is a structure, but no building, not sure if this counts....

Comment: Ruwanwalisaya is in Sri Lanka. It is in south Asia, but not East Asia.

Comment: @kl78 Interesting, I wasn't aware of the Upper Germanic-Rhaetian Limes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_Germanic-Rhaetian_Limes. Doesn't fit with this question but thanks for mentioning it :)

Comment: @ John Dee Yes, when asking the question, I didn't find anything of note for East Asia that is still standing.

Comment: The [Basilica di Santa Maria Maggiore](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_di_Santa_Maria_Maggiore)  in Rome was built in the 430's and its campanile is 75 meters (246 ft) tall.  But I haven't found if rhrme tower was built in the 5th century or not.

Comment: @Spencer. According to http://www.vatican.va/various/basiliche/sm_maggiore/en/storia/interno.htm the tower was built by Gregory XI (pope 1370 - 1378).

Comment: Please, add standard length units (meters) to parenthesis. It's really hard to read for anybody who is not used to dealing with imperial system.

Comment: @Sulthan. Noted! Will do shortly :)

Comment: Yes please. A lot of people use English as lingua franca, but just 2 countries in the World do not yet use the metric system for day to day things.

Comment: Nebuchadnezzar II's ziggurat was originally over 230 feet. That's 1/5 taller than the Hagia Sophia. Now it is 12 feet shorter. Secondly, the ziggurat is 1100 years older than the Hagia Sophia. So there is a truly ancient and larger example, which has weathered away to be slightly shorter.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'll put in the [Hagia Sophia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagia_Sophia#Basilica_of_the_Hagia_Sophia_.28current_structure.29), which reached the height of 182ft (55.6 meters) in the year 562:
[image]

> ...The emperor ordered an immediate restoration. He entrusted it to
>   Isidorus the Younger, nephew of Isidore of Miletus, who used lighter
>   materials and elevated the dome by "30 feet"[18] (about 6.25 meters or
>   20.5 feet)[clarification needed] – giving the building its current interior height of 55.6 meters (**182 ft**).[22] Moreover, Isidorus
>   changed the dome type, erecting a ribbed dome with pendentives, whose
>   diameter lay between 32.7 and 33.5 m.[18] Under Justinian's orders,
>   eight Corinthian columns were disassembled from Baalbek, Lebanon, and
>   shipped to Constantinople around 560.[23] This reconstruction, giving
>   the church its present 6th-century form, **was completed in 562**.

Not before the fall of the western Roman Empire, but (as per comments) early medieval.

- Some more technical info on the engineering involved can be read
  [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/meetings/minis/Mini4HagiaSophia.pdf)  {Thanks
  @RomaH !}

Comment: …and that's on the inside only.

Comment: Yes, inside top of dome.

Comment: This article claims the dome is approximately 2.5ft or 0.8m thick. https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/meetings/minis/Mini4HagiaSophia.pdf

Comment: @RomaH Thanks for the link! Some good info in there. I'll add it to the answer so others can read it if the comment is lost.

Comment: This is a good answer which falls within the parametres of the question (not sure why someone downvoted it...)

Comment: I suspect it may have been the time frame being *after* the fall of the Western Roman Empire. It could also be a revenge vote from comments and close votes that were *not* anonymous, as per your meta thread.

Comment: My question does say I'd also be interested in anything before 1000 AD so it must be because of one of the other reasons you mentioned (which is sad...).

Comment: Please, see the comments in the question about the imperial measurement system.

Comment: Nebbuchadnezzar II's ziggurat was originally over 230 feet. That's over 1/5 taller than this.

Answer (score 42):

I suppose that the Neolithic [Silbury Hill](http://www.english-heritage.org.uk/visit/places/silbury-hill/history/) in Wiltshire, built about 2470 - 2350 BC, is probably a contender for any list of the tallest European structures from ancient times.

At 39.3 metres (129 ft) high, I'm pretty sure it is the tallest *prehistoric* structure in Europe.

[image: Photo of Silbury Hill]
<sup>Photo by Greg O'Beirne, [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silbury_Hill#/media/File:SilburyHill_gobeirne.jpg), unchanged</sup>

Comment: An interesting prehistoric example. Strange I've never heard of it before, but then prehistory has never been my forte...

Comment: @LarsBosteen It may have been much taller when built, but natural erosion, medieval building work, and 18th-century excavations have destroyed the evidence of what might have originally been on top of the mound. Still, surviving to a height of almost 40m after almost four-and-a-half millennia is pretty impressive. :)

Comment: @LarsBosteen - Never heard it before? Its in [every single movie trailer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solsbury_Hill_(song))!

Comment: @T.E.D. Er, that would be a different hill, in a different county. :)

Comment: Hobbit skyscraper?!

Comment: @T.E.D. As sempaiscuba has already pointed out https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solsbury_Hill

Comment: @T.E.D. Two letters off, nothing crazy. :-)

Answer (score 29):

Possible currently existing candidates after the Colosseum and the Nimes Aqueduct.

at 91 feet, the aqueduct of Ferreres, tarragona, Ic B.C.
[image]

at 89 feet, the aqueduct of Segovia.

[image]

The Hercules lighttower, Galicia. 118 feet of roman building, 72 more feet added in the 1600's during a rebuild process.

[image]

a *"detailed"* plan of the roman stone structure ( no details added, no ornaments, no wood, only the stone plans as discovered):
[image]

The Alcántara bridge, 90 A.D. , 147ft height , thanks to @njuffa
[image]

Comment: Not quite competitors but worth mentioning :)

Comment: @LarsBosteen not competitors, but yes "standing" and mostly unbroken.

Comment: To this list of "still standing but not quite the tallest" structures one could add the [Alcantara bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alc%C3%A1ntara_Bridge) in Spain with a height of 45 m (~= 147 ft).

Comment: Well, they're definitely the longest!

Comment: I agree with the above stated answer. It is probably The Hercules Lighttower in La Corunna, Spain located in the Galician region of Northwestern Spain. It originally began in Roman times, though has been refined and expanded into Modern times.

Comment: The Romans were amazingly good engineers and what's even more amazing is that these aqueducts were everywhere in the Roman empire, not just single buildings like the Pyramids.

Comment: @Byte11 yeah, in my city the roman plumbering still appears here and there mostly intact. hell, in Vindolanda, england, WOODEN PLUMBING is still piping water underground, driving the archaeologists crazy (try-not-to-break-it) ( but mantaining in a perfect state any organic element below ground).

Answer (score 19):

What about the [Pantheon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheon,_Rome) in Rome, finished circa 126 AD?

It is 142 feet to the inside of its [oculus](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/oculus), and the dome adds another 1.2 metres (3.9 ft).

[image: Pantheon with dimensions]

*(shared from engineeringrome.com via CC 3.0, attibuted to Lancaster, 2005).*

Not only that, it is still is the world's largest unreinforced concrete dome, and the only one surviving from the time of the Empire.

[image: Pantheon interior from Wikipedia]

Comment: @LarsBosteen I thought the Pantheon wasn't getting enough love, either, so I added some images. If Martigan feels I've done too much, they should feel free to revert the edit once it's peer reviewed.

Answer (score 18):

[Borsippa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsippa) was a city that was closely connected to Babylon. It had a Ziggurat built by Nebbuchadnezzar II, on the site of an older building. It belonged to the god Nabu. Originally standing at 70 meters, the remains of the ziggurat are now 52 meters tall. Medieval people thought that it was the tower of Babel. Its known as the "the tongue tower" because of its distinct shape.

[image]

[Dur Kurigalzu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dur-Kurigalzu) was a city during the Old Kassite period. It was named after King Kurigalzu, c. 1375 B.C., who made it the capitol of Babylon. Bricks on the ziggurat bear the inscription of Kurgalzu II, c. 1332 B.C. The remains of the ziggurat are about 52 meters tall. The surrounding platform was rebuilt in the 90's, and its a popular destination for people in Baghdad.

I'm not sure if the OP was asking about Mesopotamia, but it is technically a part of the Near East. There was nothing in Europe close to this size until the Roman Empire.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## The Temple Mount in Jerusalem

From http://www.jerusalem-insiders-guide.com/temple-of-jerusalem.html

The dimensions for the Temple of Jerusalem were staggering: 460 meters to the east, 315 m to the north, 280 m to the south, and the western wall was 485 meters long.

The walls above ground rose 30 meters (ten stories tall), and their foundations were as deep as 20 meters in some places in order to reach bedrock. Each layer of the wall was recessed about 3 centimeters from the layer beneath it. This was to avoid the optical illusion created whenever you look up a tall, straight object, that it is about to fall over you.

Some of the quarried stones used in the Western Wall are so large that, to this day, archaeologists have trouble understanding how they could possibly have been transported. The smallest stones weight between 2 to 5 tons and the largest stone of them all – possibly the largest building stone in antiquity – is 13.6 meters long, 4.6 meters thick and 3.3 meters high, and is estimated to weigh 570 tons. The builders used dry construction – there is no cement between the stones. In fact, there’s nothing holding the stones together except their own weight.

Today, the highest point in the exposed section reaches a height of 40 meters above the bedrock

Comment: Interesting, I especially like the parts about altering construction to create the illusion of straight walls. Since this question is concerning the *height* of the ancient construction which survives to today, can you include that information?  It seems this information is mainly concerning the size when it was constructed (perhaps I misunderstand though).

Comment: from https://english.thekotel.org/kotel/about/facts_and_data/: In the past, the Western Wall rose to a height of 60 meters. Today, the highest point in the exposed section reaches a height of 40 meters above the bedrock.

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

The Jetavanaramaya in Sri Lanka, a Buddhist Stupa, is 400 feet tall.  It was built between 270 and 301 AD.  As the exact height of the Lighthouse of Alexandria is unknown, the Jetavanaramaya may have been taller.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clearer in the question (I'll edit) but I'm only interested in man-made structures in Europe and the Near East that are still standing, even if not in their entirety (but thanks for your answer anyway). :)

Comment: It was still standing there last time I checked (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetavanaramaya). I'm not sure if Sri Lanka counts as Near East, tho.

Comment: @Ape *Near East* is a Euro-centric expression meaning the region starting at the eastern end of the Mediterranean Sea and extending into roughly Iraq. There is also the *Far East*, which is roughly China, Japan, Korea etc. These expressions are a bit dated nowadays and don't make much sense if you live in Australia or Alaska.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the Lighthouse of Alexandria at an estimated height of 120 meters (423 ft).

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clearer in the question (I'll edit) but I'm only interested in man-made structures in Europe and the Near East that are still standing, even if not in their entirety (but thanks for your answer anyway). :)

Comment: maybe because it's no longer standing?

Answer (score 1):

Newgrange - Neolithic burial grounds at Newgrange are older than the Egyptian Pyramids, pre-dating Stonehenge by 1,000 years.  One of Europe’s most important prehistoric clusters.

[image]

Comment: But how tall is it?

Comment: According to the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newgrange) for this location, the height is up to 12 meters.

Comment: This is an answer to an entirely unrelated question.